# Information about the 1630/master app

Tags: networking, security, postfix, lsof, netstat

When I run

```
$ sudo netstat -a --programs | grep LISTENING | grep 1630
```

I will get [this](http://pastebin.com/53ufS1tU) output. Do you know what good are processes running under this app name? Why they are running on my system and if it's OK to have them running?

```
$ sudo lsof -Pwn | grep 1630/master
```

founds no information

```
$ find /usr -type f -perm +111 -name master
```

gives

```
/usr/lib/postfix/master
```

Is this a security problem? I don't remember I have installed mail server. Could this be installed by malicious software? Can I remove if from running processes if I don't need it?

Comment: Well, you've found the executable. It is part of postfix (email server). If you need that it's ok. If you don't, stop the service.

Comment: Postfix is installed by defaut on many distros and it's hard to imagine why somebody would choose to install *Postfix* if they pwned you, though I suppose it woud be useful for a spammer. Do you see a lot of unexpected outbound email traffic?

Comment: I guess the 1630 is incidental and will change from one reboot to the next.

Answer (score 0):

[Postfix is a Mail Transfer Agent (MTA)](http://www.postfix.org/start.html). It's what takes email messages from your Mail User Agent (MUA) like `mutt` or `pine` and delivers it to a remote machine, or locally.

This is a fairly standard piece of software and is organized in a large number of different subsystems.

It is generally not considered malicious software.

Other MTAs include `sendmail`, `exim` and `opensmtpd`.

Your system needs an MTA to handle local mail (for example, to deliver output from cron jobs). If you remove Postfix, you should install another MTA in its place.